# RestTemplate - UriTemplate cannot find the port with his regex

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm having a problem using RestTemplate trying to specify the port of the server in the URI. The problem seems to be related to the way that the uri it's builded, because I was debugging and found that in the constructor of `UriTemplate` the value of the String uriTemplate is:

```
{protocol}://{host}:{port}/{entity}/{method}
```

But when the variable `uriComponents` is initialized doing:

```
this.uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uriTemplate).build();
```

The value that is assigned is:

```
{protocol}://{host}/{port}/{entity}/{method}
```

The problem it's clear... the `:` that separates the host from the port has been converted to a `/`.

I think that the problem is the regex that it used to build uriComponents, the one for the port is: `(:(\d*))`

How should I have to build uriTemplate in order to use the port number? 
Thanks

**EDIT: code example**

I cannot post a complete code example, because it should be too long, but here is the fragments that are used for this case.

First, the definition of the constants and base url:

```
protected static final String PROPERTY_METHOD = "method";
protected static final String PROPERTY_ENTITY = "entity";
protected static final String PROPERTY_HOST = "host";
protected static final String PROPERTY_PORT = "port";
protected static final String PROPERTY_PROTOCOL = "protocol";

protected static final String PROPERTY_BASE_URL = String.format(
        "{%s}://{%s}:{%s}/{%s}/{%s}", PROPERTY_PROTOCOL,
         PROPERTY_HOST, PROPERTY_PORT, PROPERTY_ENTITY, PROPERTY_METHOD);
```

There are attributes initialized by setter injection for those constants, and I have a method to build a map with the values:

```
protected Map<String, Object> buildBaseUrlVariables() {
    Map<String, Object> query = new HashMap<>();
    query.put(PROPERTY_PROTOCOL, getHttpProtocol());
    query.put(PROPERTY_HOST, getHostName());
    query.put(PROPERTY_PORT, getPort());
    query.put(PROPERTY_ENTITY, getEntityName());
    query.put(PROPERTY_METHOD, getMethod());
    return query;
}
```

At last, I have a method to do a Post, when `urlTemplate` is the constant defined above.

```
protected <T> T genericPostData(String urlTemplate, Class<T> class1, Map<String, Object> urlVariables) {
    LOGGER.debug("posting data for  class {} template:{} data:{}",
            new Object[] { class1, urlTemplate, urlVariables });
    try {
        return getRestTemplate().postForObject(urlTemplate, urlVariables, class1,
                urlVariables);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        analizeHttpClientErrorException(e);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw new DataAccessException(e);
    }
    return null;
```

}

When this urlTemplate it's processed by the restTemplate and the things I said above, the `:` is changed to a `/`

Comment: Can you give a code example? `fromUriString` expects a `String`, not a `UriTemplate`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've added a code example in the original post, thanks

Comment: I have a similar problem and I have filed an [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12123) in the Spring Jira.

Comment: @Rumal is this resolved? Do you consider it a Spring bug?